# glMapBufferRange() downloads full buffer?

Tags: opengl, optimization, buffer

I noticed a 15ms slow down when calling some openGL functions. After some tests I do believe I narrowed down the issue. I do have a buffer of couple MBytes (containing mostly particles). I do need to add some particles sometimes. To do so I bind the buffer, get the current number of particles to know the offset whereto write, then write the particles. As expected, the slow down is on the reading part. (For this problem, do assume that keeping track of the number of particles on the CPU side is impossible.)

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_buffer);
GLvoid* rangePtr = glMapBufferRange( //This function takes 15ms to return
    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
    m_offsetToCounter, 
    sizeof(GLuint), 
    1);
if(rangePtr != NULL)
    value = *(GLuint*) rangePtr;
m_functions->glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

I assumed by providing a really limited size (here a GLuint), only a GLuint would be downloaded. However, by reducing drastically the size of my buffer to 200 KBytes, the execution time of the function drops to 8ms.

Two question :

1. `glMapBufferRange` as well as `glGetBufferSubData` do download the full buffer even though the user only ask for a portion of it ?
2. The math doesn't add up, any idea why ? There is still 8ms to download a really small buffer. The execution time equation looks like y = ax + b where b is 7-8 ms. When I was trying to find the source of the problem before suspecting the buffer size, I also found that `glUniform*` functions took ~10ms as well. But only the first call. If there is multiple `glUniform*` calls one after the other, only the first one takes a lot of time. The others are instantaneous. And when the buffer will be accessed in reading, there is no download time as well. Is `glUniform*` triggering something ?

I'm using the Qt 5 API. I would like to be sure first that I'm using openGL properly before thinking it might be Qt's layer that causes the slow down and re-implement the whole program with glu/glut.

Comment: The last argument to `glMapBufferRange` should be a symbolic constant. Why are you passing in `1` and not `GL_MAP_READ_BIT`?

Comment: Unfortunately `GL_MAP_READ_BIT` isn't defined in Qt 5.2 OpenGL module. I had to provide the raw value. But this is not the subject here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8ms sounds like an awful lot of time… How do you measure that time?

> glMapBufferRange as well as glGetBufferSubData do download the full buffer even though the user only ask for a portion of it?

The OpenGL specification does not define in which way buffer mapping is to be implemented by the implementation. It may be a full download of the buffers contents. It may be a single page I/O-Memory mapping. It may be anything the makes the contents of the buffer object appear in the host process address space.

> The math doesn't add up, any idea why?

For one thing the smallest size of a memory map is the system's page size. Either if it's done by a full object copy or by a I/O-Memory mapping or something entirely different, you're always dealing with memory chunks at least a few kiB in size.

> I'm using the Qt 5 API

Could it be that you're using the Qt5 OpenGL functions class? AFAIK this class does load function pointers on demand, so the first invocation of a function may trigger a chain of actions that take a few moments to complete.

Comment: The time is measred using a QTime object. `start()` and `elpased()`, nothing more. For the download behaviour, since you say it may be everything even a yacht, I'll use a single buffer for the particles that will be shared with a multitude of small hashmap buffers. This way I'll never download the heavy part (the particle list). Few KBytes of download shouldn't take 8ms though :/. I am using `QOpenGLFunctions*`. Do you think I might have a good surprise re-implementing my code using glu/glut ?

Comment: @agrum: You can keep using Qt, but I suggest you use a different function loader. Something like GLEW or better yet [https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home](glloadgen). Also I'm not sure if the values reported by QTime may be a bit too coarse. One normally wants to use a high resolution timer for this.

Comment: I'll stick to QTime as so far it never deceived me. However thanks for redirecting me to other functions loader. I'll give them a try.

Comment: @agrum: The problem isn't `QTime` but the way you measure the times. The GL works asynchronously, but mapping a buffer that way will trigger a synchronization, so that the call blocks until the GPU has finished. So what you are measuring is just _anything_.

Comment: @derhass: mapping a buffer does not neccesarily introduce a synchronization point. If it's a read only mapping and the buffer has not been used as destination of OpenGL operations, then no synchronization is necessary. Also if it's a write only mapping the mapping does not not introduce a synchronization point (this is kind of the same situation as calling glBuffer[Sub]Data on a buffer object that has been used as data source right before; the OpenGL implementation of course has to deal with the dirty details (creating of a shadow buffer and so on).

Comment: @agrum: Speking of access modes: I just noticed that the access parameter of your glMapBufferRange call is invalid. It must be one of GL_MAP_READ_BIT, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT or GL_MAP_READ_BIT|GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT. The OpenGL specification does not define exact numeric values for those tokens!

Comment: @datenwolf: Well, my comment was not meant for the general case. I think this is exactly what the OP is doing: reading the particle data back from the GPU. But I might be wrong here, the pasted code doesn't tell.

Comment: @datenwolf: As said in the comment section of the original post, `GL_MAP_READ_BIT` is not defined in the Qt OpenGL API (kinda weird but meh). So I looked around and 1 seemed to map to what I wanted, even though I know it's dirty. http://docs.factorcode.org:8080/content/word-GL_MAP_READ_BIT,opengl.gl.html

Comment: @derhass : My point also asking why the 8-10ms of waiting happens when I also call `glUniform` before reading the buffer for example. There is a synchronization happening but I can't put the finger on it. Is there a neat way to know what is going on on the GPU side ?